# How can I arrange one property of my mock to set another property?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, justmock

So I'm trying to mock an interface that contains a property that my unit test has to set initially, which is then altered by the subject under test, and then my assertion looks at the result.

The code under test looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    IEnumerable<int> IntList { get; set; }

    public void Bar(IBaz baz)
    {
        if (baz == null)
            throw new ApplicationException();

        if (baz.IntList == null)
            baz.IntList = new List<int>();

        this.IntList = baz.IntList;
    }
}
```

I'm mocking my interface in a factory like this:

```
public class BazFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<int> IntList { get; set; }

    public IBaz Create()
    {
        IBaz baz = Mock.Create<IBaz>();
        baz.Arrange(x => x.IntList).Returns(this.IntList);
        return baz;
    }
}
```

And my unit test consumes it all like this:

```
[Fact]
public void WithNullIntList_InitializesNew()
{
    //Arrange
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    BazFactory factory = new BazFactory();
    IBaz baz = factory.Create();

    //Act
    foo.Bar(baz);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(foo.IntList);
}
```

Obviously, this isn't working, because though `foo.Bar()` tries to change `baz.IntList`, it still returns `factory.IntList`, which hasn't changed.

What I need is to be able to arrange `baz.IntList` so that **when it is set, the value passed to it is diverted** to `factory.IntList` instead. I have only seen documentation on how to do this with a variable inside the mock class, and how to do it with a method, but not with a property's setter.

I feel like I should be able to add a line to `BazFactory.Create()` like this, but the following code doesn't work.

```
baz.ArrangeSet(x => this.IntList = x.IntList);
```

How can I express "the value passed to `baz.IntList`" in the context of an action?

If it makes a difference, I am using the Lite version of JustMock.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Include the method under test and how it relates to the mocked interface. What you have provided so far is incomplete, making it too broad to isolate the problem. You are most likely using the wrong type to store the items but can't confirm with the current example provided.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks! Look better now?